# How to pass a string to omnetpp simulation from the command prompt

Tags: c++, omnet++

In my .ned file I have a simple module

```
simple Txc1
{
    parameters:
        int dummy_number = default(10);
}
```

When I run the simulation from the command prompt by specifying `dummy_number` I want i.e.,

```
opp_run -l tictoc omnetpp.ini --**.dummy_number=15
```

`dummy_number` equals 15 in my simulation.
But when instead of integer I want to specify a string

```
simple Txc1
{
    parameters:
        string dummy_string = default("Some dummy string");
}
```

```
opp_run -l tictoc omnetpp.ini --**.dummy_string="Test"
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot evaluate parameter 'dummy_string':(omnetpp::cModule)Tictoc1: unknown parameter 'Test' -- in module (Txc1) Tictoc1.tic (id=2), during network setup
```

Why my string is perceived as a parameter when it is just a value and how do I circumvent the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your string does not contain a space, add backslashes before quotes, i.e.:

```
opp_run -l tictoc omnetpp.ini --**.dummy_string=\"TestWithoutSpace\"
```

Comment: It works! But what if I want to send a string with space?

Comment: It seems that currently there is no way to parse a string parameter that contains a space.